# Executable jar in eclipse is not runnable

Tags: java, eclipse, runnable

After I finished making a program in java on eclipse, and decided to make a runnable jar I went through all the correct processes and created it. When I tried to run it later, I clicked on it, but nothing happened! Is this because I only have one class or do I need to do somthing else? 
Ps. It runs perfectly fine in eclipse.

Comment: Did you try running it using command?

Comment: Is it a console application or a swing application?

Comment: By meaning I clicked on it,did you mean double clicking the jar??

Answer (score 0):

run it from command prompt, if it just outputs to console then you may not see anything by double click run java -jar xxxx.jar

Comment: if it just outputs to console no gui then run it from command prompt (cmd)

Comment: when I try this it just says Error: Could not find or load main class island_survival.java what is wrong?

Comment: are u sure about making jar file correctly also defining main class, if u are using eclipse when making jar it will ask for main class, fill that with appropriate class name

Comment: *"main class island_survival.java"*  Was that copy/pasted?  It should be more like `main class island_survival.class`.  The source file has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a JAR file have manifesto file attached to it which hold the class file which contains main method.If you have created your program in eclipse with main method in the selected class and created jar file than it won't make any issue.Anyways re-create it by simply clean and build,go through the dist folder in your project it will have an executable jar file ready for you.

For console application you wont be able to see the output directly on the windows screen but only on command prompt by running the file by java -jar jarfilename.Else any frame or swing application will run atomatically on windows screen by double click.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `java -cp yourjar.jar com.example.Main` where `yourjar.jar` is the name of your jar file and `com.example.Main` is the full name of the class containing your main method( including the package name)